# How to display most used ports when analyzing packets in Wireshark?

Tags: port, wireshark, packet

I've collected an array of packets on Wireshark and i'm wondering how do I filter that properly to see the most used ports / protocols?

I'd assume it'd be within "Analyze" "Filters" and then you'd have to create a specific one if this is the way of doing it, although I am unsure of how to properly express that in code.

I'd assume I dont need to provide any images of data for this query but if I should, please let me know

Any ideas?

How can I find out the traffic flow rates of my packets in Wireshark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  go to "statistics" then "ipv4" or "ipv6" depending of your network, then "destinations and ports".

It will give you the most used port and protocol.

Then you can just apply a filter by entering something like tcp.port == the_port in the searchbar (you have to replace tcp by the most used protocol and the_port by the port that you want to filter).
concerning the flow rate, you can find it with the flow graph. (again in statistics menu).

Have a nice day

JC

Comment: What is the == the_port supposed to return? When I input tcp.port it displays the count which is fine, just not sure what the_port entails

Comment: Also I included one last question that just came up if you'd be able to answer

Comment: I edited my reponse, if it is still unclear feel free to add another comment.